# How to create an HMAC in crystal-lang

Tags: hmac, crystal-lang

See the [OpenSSL::HMAC documentation](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.23.0/OpenSSL/HMAC.html).

I am trying this:

```
require "openssl"

puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(:sha256, "secret key", "data")
```

and I am getting this error:

> undefined constant OpenSSL::HMAC

Other OpenSSL methods are working fine, like `OpenSSL::Digest.new("SHA256")`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `require "openssl"` [you don't require `hmac`](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/7bbb400625e8cac68803e7c802289c2d14e499ec/src/openssl.cr#L130-L134). This works for me:

```
require "openssl/hmac"

puts OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(:sha256, "secret key", "data")
```